# Xcode: Reading of Array from dataFile

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I've encountered a problem of which I am trying to read an Array from a dataFile.

I have a dataFile.h and dataFile.m

**dataFile.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface dataFile : NSObject

@end
```

**dataFile.m**

```
#import "dataFile.h"

@implementation dataFile

-(void)Data

{
    NSArray  * myArray2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"f",@"b",@"z",nil];
}

@end
```

I have another ViewController which is supposed to read *myArray2* from **dataFile.m**

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *Label;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "dataFile.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // The code here doesn't seem to be working to read myArray2

    _Label.text = [myArray2 indexOfObject:2];

}
```

Basically what is supposed to happen is that *myArray2* will get called into **ViewController** and then gets set as a text for a label.

However it seems to get stuck at the point of reading. As it doesn't seem possible to use the code without Xcode throwing up errors.

Comment: Data file can be treated as an object so you have to make an instance of that object to access its attributes. What is _S1C1Char?

Comment: @user2438604 oops, _S1C1Char is actually just the *Label declared in the .h file

Comment: please use the recommended Cocoa naming convention: class names begin with a uppercase letter, property and method names begin with a lowercase letter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to expose your NSArray from dataFile in your interface and use it in your videDidLoad. In you sample NSArray defined locally and not visible outside of Data method. Here is how change may looks like.

**dataFile.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface dataFile : NSObject
+(NSArray *)Data;
@end
```

**dataFile.m**

```
#import "dataFile.h"

@implementation dataFile

+(NSArray *)Data

{
    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"f",@"b",@"z",nil];
}

@end
```

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *Label;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "dataFile.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];    
    _Label.text = [[dataFile Data] indexOfObject:2];

}
@end
```

Comment: This solution seems to work for me, However Xcode is pushing to me this error `Implicit conversion of 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'NSString * __nullable' is disallowed with ARC` and `Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'id __nonnull' is disallowed with ARC`

Comment: I figured out the problem with the proposed code. In **ViewController.m** where it says `_Label.text = [[dataFile Data] indexOfObject:2];`, it should be replaced with `_Label.text = [[dataFile Data] objectAtIndex:2];` instead